# Pass the output of PowerShell script to Jenkins Parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get a list of Vsphere templates and use them as parameters in Jenkins.
I have tried using a function and running the PowerShell command.

```
def findtemplates() {
  def $vmTemplate = "powershell -command 'Connect-VIServer -server server -User user -Password pass -Force; Get-Template | select name'"
    return $vmTemplate
}
```

And in parameter section:

```
      parameters {
    choice(name: 'Template', choices: findtemplates(), description: 'test')
  }
```

But does not work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [`powershell`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-windows-powershell-script) step (or [`pwsh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#pwsh-powershell-core-script) for PS 7+) with argument `returnStdout: true` to get the output of the PowerShell command:

```
def findtemplates() {
  return powershell( returnStdout: true, script: '''
      Connect-VIServer -server server -User user -Password pass -Force
      Get-Template | select name'
    ''')
}
```

Note the use of `'''` to pass a multiline script to the `powershell` step.

I guess you hardcoded user name and password only for brevity. A more complete example would look like:

```
def findtemplates() {                       
  withCredentials([ usernamePassword( credentialsId: 'ReplaceWithYourCredentialsId',
                                      usernameVariable: 'VIServerUser', 
                                      passwordVariable: 'VIServerPassword') ]) {
                
     return powershell( returnStdout: true, script: '''
       Connect-VIServer -server server -User $env:VIServerUser -Password $env:VIServerPassword -Force
       Get-Template | select name'
     ''')
                        
  }
}
```

Note the use of environment variables instead of Groovy string interpolation for security reasons (see [String interpolation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation)).

Comment: Thanks, It solved my issue. Just the only thing that was missing is to put the code in a node block. node {}